# why does my call & sms filter no longer work?

Tags: call-sms-filter

Is there any way to block unwanted calls and texts as the filter no longer seems to work and any apps I've found aren't compatible

Comment: Did this start failing after a system update? Have you tried a hard reset?

Answer (score 2):

Try to download "SysApp Pusher" application from the store and once it's downloaded, open it, look for call+sms filter and check if there is an update available for it, if yes download it if no then look for extras+info and update it, if the same issue occur, you might need to perform a factory reset on the device